# Image resize button missing

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm new to Blender and currently still learning. I have a scene file that is over 100 MB, I and I can't upload that huge file online. In order to reduce the size, I tried to resize the textures but all I get are these:

[image]

I wonder where did the resize option go and is there any other way to resize the textures?
Any help from a blender expert would be really useful

Comment: yes the Resize function should be here, is it the same with other versions of Blender?

Comment: Yeah, it's the same everywhere, well it is the same in 2.79

Comment: Nevermind, here it is https://pasteall.org/pic/b3b54f0a6e6e490bb418fe9a11634f5a

Comment: it works for me, maybe share your file itself, delete everything except the picture so that we can test with your actual file

Comment: Untextured file?

Comment: My file is over 100 MB, pasteall doesn't support it

Comment: I used Google drive

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PSUPqqeJ_7z85omNZ0Anlcpv41zy9jVc?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-_a6HsIzKEAE3pSSf-mMvn9GGDTPHS8o/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think this should work

Comment: so yes that's weird because it works for me, I hope someone will have an idea why it doesn't for you, see my screenshot: https://zupimages.net/up/21/45/14p0.jpg

Comment: can you resize it for me then? or reduce the file size yourself? I'm not sure what to do now

Comment: what size do you need? If you need to resize pictures you have plenty of image apps like Krita which is free, you can even do it online with https://www.photopea.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I used Adobe Photoshop. Don't seem to work in Blender, God knows why